# onclick event does not trigger when appended

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have the code below...
When clicking on the li that gets added dynamically, the onclick does not trigger.but when I hardcode the generated li (555 Palm Dr, Burbank, CA, USA) and click it triggers the event.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control-searchbox" placeholder="Search Here" id="searchbox" onkeypress="OnKeyPressAutoFill(this.value, event);">
            <ul id="ul_autocomplete_result" class="sbOptions ui-menu ulZindex"></ul>

function OnKeyPressAutoFill(val, e) {
        var event = window.event ? window.event : e;
        console.log(event.keyCode)

        if (gleble_counter < 0) gleble_counter = 0;
        if (event.keyCode == 40) {
            NextAddress(parseInt(gleble_counter));
            gleble_counter = parseInt(gleble_counter) + 1;
        } else if (event.keyCode == 38) {
            gleble_counter = parseInt(gleble_counter) - 1;
            PreviousAddress(parseInt(gleble_counter));
        } else if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            OnSelectLocation(parseInt(gleble_counter));
        } else if (event.keyCode == 9) {
            $("#div_addresses").html('');
            $("#div_selected_address").html('');
            $("#ul_autocomplete_result").html('');
        } else {
            gleble_counter = 0;

            var availableTags = [];
            $("#div_addresses").html('');
            $("#div_selected_address").html('');
            $("#ul_autocomplete_result").html('');

            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            var location = val;

            if (geocoder) {
                geocoder.geocode({ 'address': location }, function (results, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                        for (var i = 0; i <= results.length - 1; i++) {
                            console.log(results[i].formatted_address);
                            $("#ul_autocomplete_result").append('<li onclick="OnLiSelect(' + i + ')" style="cursor:pointer" id="li_' + i + '">' + results[i].formatted_address + '</li>');
                        }
                        console.log(availableTags);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

    function OnLiSelect(val) {
        $("#searchbox").val($('#li_' + val).text());
        OnSelectLocation(val);
    }
```

Comment: You're right. You need to use `addEventListener();`

Comment: jQuery event delegation is better - if you must use jQuery :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `<li>` elements are dynamically generated, you will need to use event delegation.

```
$( "#ul_autocomplete_result" ).on( "click", "li", OnLiSelect );
```

Change `OnLiSelect` function to:

```
function OnLiSelect() {
    var val = $(this).text(); // get val for 'this'
    $("#searchbox").val(val);
    OnSelectLocation(val);
}
```

Also, no need to set IDs to the dynamically added LIs.

Read up: [jQuery Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: I wish you a long happy and healthy life.

Comment: @Sev Thank you, you too :)